# Records in the database do not update

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-jpa

Here is a part of Simulation entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Simulation")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Simulation extends BaseEntity
{
    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "population_count")
    private long populationCount;
    @Column(name = "initial_infected_number")
    private long initialInfectedNumber;
    @Column(name = "r_number")
    private double infectionRate;
    @Column(name = "mortality_rate")
    private double mortalityRate;
    @Column(name = "disease_duration")
    private int diseaseDuration;
    @Column(name = "time_of_dying")
    private int timeOfDying;
    @Column(name = "days_of_simulation")
    private int daysOfSimulation;
    @Column(name = "protection_duration")
    private int protectionDuration;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "simulation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Record> records;
}
```

And Record entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Record")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Record extends BaseEntity
{
    @Column(name = "Infected_Count")
    private long infectedCount;
    @Column(name = "Susceptible_To_Infection")
    private long susceptibleToInfection;
    @Column(name = "Death_Count")
    private long deathCount;
    @Column(name = "Resistant_Count")
    private long resistantCount;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="simulation_id")
    private Simulation simulation;
}
```

service class (update method):

```
@Service
public class SimulationService implements ISimulationService{
    @Autowired
    SimulationRepository simulationRepository;

    @Override
    public Simulation save(Simulation simulation) {
        return simulationRepository.save(simulation);
    }

    @Override
    public Simulation findByName(String name) {
        return simulationRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Simulation> findAll() {
        return simulationRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Simulation update(Simulation simulation) {
        Simulation simulationFromDB = simulationRepository.findByName(simulation.getName());

        simulationFromDB.setProtectionDuration(simulation.getProtectionDuration());
        simulationFromDB.setInfectionRate(simulation.getInfectionRate());
        simulationFromDB.setDaysOfSimulation(simulation.getDaysOfSimulation());
        simulationFromDB.setDiseaseDuration(simulation.getDiseaseDuration());
        simulationFromDB.setInitialInfectedNumber(simulation.getInitialInfectedNumber());
        simulationFromDB.setMortalityRate(simulation.getMortalityRate());
        simulationFromDB.setName(simulation.getName());
        simulationFromDB.setPopulationCount(simulation.getPopulationCount());
        simulationFromDB.setTimeOfDying(simulation.getTimeOfDying());
        simulationFromDB.createRecords();

        return simulationRepository.save(simulationFromDB);
    }
}
```

I have no problems adding simulations and records to the database, but when I want to update the simulation with new records, I only update simulation and add new records with same simulation_id. Did I make any mistake or forgot to do somethink? Thanks for your answers.

EDIT:
I added orphanRemoval = true to simulation entity but now Im getting this stacktrace:

```
2020-12-30 13:07:03.603 ERROR 15592 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested except
ion is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.example.CovidPandemySimulation.domain.agregate.Simulation.records; nest
ed exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.example.CovidPandemySimulation.domain.agregate.Simulation.records] with root
 cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.example.CovidPandemySimulation.domain.agregate.Simulation.records
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.lambda$flushCollections$1(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.forEachCollectionEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1136) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.
Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.
jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.CovidPandemySimulation.application.service.SimulationService.update(SimulationService.java:46) ~[main/:na]
        at com.example.CovidPandemySimulation.presentation.SimulationController.updateByName(SimulationController.java:50) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Do somebody know where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can perhapst try with saveorUpdate() to update an existing object. As i know save() generates new idendifier and perform "Insert into" in db. saveOrUpdate() can both save and update.

Comment: the db simulation is updated without it, the problem is that old records are still in the database

Comment: after adding oprhanRemoval Im getting stacktrace like this in my post